# iphone app - load cell image from XML element

Tags: iphone, xml, uitableview, xml-parsing

I need some help to figure this out ..

I am getting data from the XML, one of the elements is the Image file Name "Icon1.png", images are save on my resources locally, at the moment I can load the icon1.png with this code

```
// retrieve an image
NSString *imageicon = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                       pathForResource:@"icon2" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *cellicon = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imageicon];

//set the image on the table cell
cell.imageView.image = cellicon;
```

but i want to load the icon file name from the XML element

```
<dimage>icon2.png</dimage>
```

how can I load the image to my cell ? - Solved

part 2 - selected row go to bclass description view controller,

```
-(void)viewDidLoad { 
self.title = bclass.title; 
[self.textView setText:bclass.description]; 
[self.destag setText:bclass.descimg]; 
}
```

at the moment "discing" is just showing the image name (UItextView), but i want to display the image on a UIImageView.

Thanks for your help.

Hernando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the image file name from XML file to a `NSString`, and then create an `UIImage` using the

`+(UIImage*)imageNamed:(NSString*)name` class method of an `UIImage` object:

**Example**

```
NSString *imageName = ... read the name from xml.

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works , one more question how do I display that image in a UIImageview in a different view? Thanks

Comment: Need to see how you set it up to help you with that.

Comment: Hi <code>  - (void)viewDidLoad {
 self.title = bclass.title;
    [self.textView setText:bclass.description];
    [self.destag setText:bclass.descimg]; 

}

Comment: at the moment the "descimg" is just showing the file name on UITextview. I know i need to convert the NString to a Image and Display on UIImageViewer .. thanks